# Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 41 ,"Metadata"[a-zA-Z0-9:{}" ,+()[]\_==*]*[}]

Tags: java

Actual Metadata object ::

```
,"Metadata":{"ModifiedDate":"Thu Dec 10 20151046","CreatedDate":"Thu Dec 10 2015 10:46:30 GMT+0530 (IST)","HiddenRule":"[{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Gender\",\"data_type\":\"String\",\"internal_name\":\"gender\",\"class\":\"Open\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"==\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"==\",\"class\":\"Oper\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"\\\"sd\\\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\\\"sd\\\"\",\"class\":\"Cons\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"}]"}
```

Trying to search for the "Metadata" object, in the JSON string and replace it with a blank. Basically remove the object from the JSON string.
,\"Metadata\"[a-zA-Z0-9:{}" ,+()[]\_==*]*[}]. But when compiled in the JAVA program, am facing the exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 41
,"Metadata"[a-zA-Z0-9:{}" ,+()[]\_==*]*[}]
                                         ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2493)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
    at temp.main(temp.java:20)

    String str=",\"Metadata\":{\"ModifiedDate\":\"Thu Dec 10 20151046\",\"CreatedDate\":\"Thu Dec 10 2015 10:46:30 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"HiddenRule\":\"[{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Gender\",\"data_type\":\"String\",\"internal_name\":\"gender\",\"class\":\"Open\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"==\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"==\",\"class\":\"Oper\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"\\\"sd\\\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\\\"sd\\\"\",\"class\":\"Cons\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"data_type\":\"operator\",\"internal_name\":\"\"}]\"}";
        String regexes = ",\"Metadata\"[a-zA-Z0-9:{}\" ,+()[]\\_==*]*[}]";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regexes, "Hi!!!"));
```

Comment: That's what you get for parsing JSON with regex.

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are special character in regex. you have to escape it.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9:{}" ,+()\[\]\_==*\]*[}]
```

Comment: escaped it in the new code. But Matcher class's find method is returning false for the last part of the regex, i.e., [}
]